# Making ears and build through hudson

Tags: java, maven, ant, groovy, jenkins

We have more then 250 applications in our project . Till now we were doing there full build (i.e packaging making ear) through ant scripts which were suppose to run on AIX build machines where we had the ksh scripts to build ear and they were supposed to be ready at a place on the AIX server itself.

But now we have started mavenizing our applications using pom through hudson so we need a solution as to how to build ears for these applications through hudson as now onwards we can't use AIX server to build ear of applications.When we build applications one by one we have the ear for that component only but it would be tiring to build one by one as we have 250 plus applications. I have seen a groovy scripts which runs through jenkins but dont know exactly how it works and does groovy script also need any AIX server to run ?? I also have a thinking that can we make a dependency tree and include it in a parent pom through which we can trigger build so that components get build one by one starting from the lowest dependent component.. is that possible or suggest sumthing else???

Suggest something so taht we can build ears and zips of our application through hudson.

Comment: I think groovy scripts just need some jars and a JVM to run

Comment: I need complete info as to how to trigger build through hudson

Comment: You can trigger a build in Hudson simply by clicking on the build button? May be i misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ear file via the [maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/). If you like to make zip files you can use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create archives like zip, tar, tar.gz etc.
If you are using Hudson you can start several builds in parallel.

If your application has many modules which depend on each other it might worth thinking about multi-module builds to see if you can cut the modules appropriately and build them in one go.